# Lora duplex communication

Tags: send, duplex, lora

I wrote codes for simple a gateway and a node. gateway send a message to node. but after 5 or 6 times send and receive, the node is hanging and not receive from gateway.
I attach the codes below

sender:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka4U1.jpg)

receiver: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yrjO.jpg)

result is not permanent. gateway send 4 or 5 time to node but after that node can't receive anything.!!! I tried many changes in my code but at first lets discuss about this simple one. please help me. thanks.

Comment: Please add a minimal, reproducible example of you problem to the question, external links and images are discouraged.

Comment: David, please add your code as text, never as images

Comment: @gerum it is, only thing that is missing is what tranceiver is being used.